# get the text content from a contenteditable div through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want retrieve the text content from a contentEditable div through javascript. What are the options of doing this? I've tried innerHTML but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're serious about getting help then please post and example of what you're trying to do or a test case for us to use to solve the problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use jQuery and do

`var content = $('#my-contenteditable-div').html();`

also look up these links:

http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/778165.aspx

[Extracting text from a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: really no need for jQuery here.

Comment: Will include HTML for new lines

Comment: will include all html in general

Answer (score 60):

Why not use textContent for this:

```
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
    text = contenteditable.textContent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4W8y/1/

Comment: Because textContent doesn't respect newlines (in chrome at least)

Answer (score 33):

Unfortunately, I've found that `innerText` is the only way to preserve newlines in contenteditable dom nodes. What I'm doing (tested only in chrome at the moment) is this:

```
 var innerText = editableDiv.innerText  // using innerText here because it preserves newlines
 if(innerText[innerText.length-1] === '\n') 
     innerText = innerText.slice(0,-1)             // get rid of weird extra newline
 return innerText
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer while not using jQuery. BTW, I use `trim()` to get rid of starting and trailing blanks.

Comment: On Chromium 78 and Firefox 71, when I type `a<enter><enter>b` on the div, I get `a\n\n\nb` (3 newlines rather than the expected 2). Is this expected? Is there a way to work around it? [Test program](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirodown/blob/3473e7f1c5941c3cd3f879185e44edecab136615/editor.html#L52) with [this patch](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirodown/issues/2).

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 you're the only acknowledgement of this problem I can find.  N line terminators become 2N-1 line terminators. My desperate workaround:  `string.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')`.  Unfortunately it's not consistent. This almost-doubling crime happens on _typed_ newlines, not _pasted_ newlines.

Comment: @BobStein yeah, I just gave up on this and moved to a proper Js editor like Monaco: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 wow what an editor, Microsoft does a few things right. For current works I don't even need markup. But I get the sense contenteditable is a sinking island.

Comment: textContent from the other answers seems better if you don't need multiline as innerText seems to also return &nbsp;, double spaces and such

Answer (score 7):

`lblMailContent` is the id of editable field.

```
var details= document.getElementById("lblMailContent").innerHTML;
```

Put this code in `clientClick`. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way, because i need html-input:

```
message = $('<div>').html(
   $('#area').html()
   .replace(/<(div|p|br)[^<]*?>/g, '&lt;br /&gt;')
   .replace(/<([(i|a|b|u)^>]+)>(.*?)<\/\1>/gim,
      function(v) { return '' + escape(v) + ''; })
).text();
```

Allows the tags A, B, I, U and replaces Divs and Ps with BRs

Comment: Are you sure you want to parse HTML with regexps?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

````js
function textFromDiv(selector) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  const text = element.html().replace(/<div>/g,"\n").replace(/<\/div>/g,"").replace(/<br>/g,"\n");
  return text;
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS solution

html:

```
<div 
  contenteditable="true"
  onkeyup="myFunction(this, event)"
></div>
```

js:

```
function myFunction(self, event){
  console.log(self.innerText) 
  console.log(event)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using text content, working fine in most of the cases
Working Example:  [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/rakeshraih/6argbk9d/2/)(verified in Safari)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my spin at it...

```
input = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

input.onkeyup = function(){
    text = "";
    for(i=0; i<input.childNodes.length; i++){
        text += input.childNodes[i].textContent + "\n";
    }
    text = text.trim();
    console.log(text);
}
```