# How do I select value from editable div in meteor instead of using textarea.value?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I used textarea tag instead this div[contentEditable="true]  before, but it have an issue with text resizing on user typing;
and this is **the code, that worked in textarea version:**

```
Template.mainFrame.events({
  'click button': function(e, t) {
    var inputted = t.find('#textarea').value;
    Session.set('input', inputted);
    t.find('#textarea').value = '';
  }
});

Template.mainFrame.someValue = function(){
    return Session.get('input');
};
```

**html:**

```
  <section>
        <div class="input">
          <div contentEditable="true" placeholder="type here" id="textarea">
            Lorem ipsum sit dolor
          </div>
          <button>
            click me
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
          {{#markdown}}
    {{someValue}}
          {{/markdown}}
        </div>
      </section>
```

But now it is not working; I guess **.value** method only could be applicable to textarea or inputs and this kind of stuff;

**So, the question is: which method in meteor do I use to select content inside div?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a meteor question, but really just about javascript (or jQuery to be precise).

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593626/get-the-text-content-from-a-contenteditable-div-through-javascript) is that you can use:

```
var inputted = t.find('#textarea').html();
```

Comment: yeah, thank you; this was very helpful, I used .textContent, .html() not working either