# Get content from contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I display a popup for the user where it is required to write some text, and I want to check if he wrote something to display the message accordingly.

HTML

```
<div id="pop-div-id" class="cont-pop-div">
  <p id="content-id" contenteditable="true" class="cont-pop" placeholder="type explanation" spellcheck="false"></p>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript. I commented the use of `textContent` because I kept getting `content` has `undefined` value. The issue here is that this always alerts `You have to write something` and I am not sure what I am doing wrong that the value is not being updated even if I write something there.

```
let content =  document.getElementById("content-id");
// let contentValue = content.textContent;
// console.log(contentValue);

let innerText = content.innerText;

   if (innerText[innerText.length-1] === '\n') { 
      innerText = innerText.slice(0,-1);
      console.log(innerText);
   }            

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (innerText.length === 0 || !!innerText.trim()) {
     alert("You have to write something ");
  } else {
     alert("Hello");
  }
});
```

I have seen this similar post - [get the text content from a contenteditable div through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593626/get-the-text-content-from-a-contenteditable-div-through-javascript)
but apparently I am doing something wrong

Comment: Is this a typo on stack overflow only or in your code as well? document.getElementById("content--id");  ==> document.getElementById("content-id");

In js you use 'content--id' while html is saying 'content-id'

Comment: @Stinodotbe good catch !, but unfortunately it is only stack overflow typo. I updated the post.

Comment: @user12051965 `innerText` only returns the text content. If you need the entire content, use `innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `innerHTML` attribute

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  Hello World!
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150'>
</div>
```

[MDN reference for innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

If you want to only get the text and not any HTML inside it, use `innerText`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText) // Will not include <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150'>
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  Hello World!
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150'>
</div>
```

[MDN reference for innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)