# Javascript regex: find a word NOT followed by space character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I need javascript regex that will match words that are NOT followed by space character and has @ before, like this:

@bug  -  finds "@bug", because no space afer it

@bug and me  -  finds nothing because there is space after "@bug"

@bug and @another  -  finds "@another" only

@bug and @another and something  -  finds nothing because both words are followed by space.

Help?
Added:
string is fetched from  and FF puts it's own tags at end of it. Although I basically need only the last word starting with @, $ (end-of-string) can not be used.

Comment: When you say *"not followed by space character"*, are you really saying *"is at the end of the string"*? They're not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: No, it is from contenteditable div and FF puts it's own tags at the end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `re = /@\w+\b(?! )/`. This looks for a word (making sure it captures the whole word) and uses a negative lookahead to make sure the word is not followed by a space.

Using the setup above:

```
var re = /@\w+\b(?! )/, // etc etc

for ( var i=0; i<cases.length; i++ ) {
    print( re2.exec(cases[i]) )
}

//prints
@bug
null
@another
null
```

The only way this won't work is if your word ends in an underscore and you wanted that punctuation to be part of the word: For example '@bug and @another_ blahblah' will pick out @another since `@another` wasn't followed by a space.
This doesn't seem very likely but if you wanted to deal with that case too, you could use `/@\w+\b(?![\w ]/` and that would return `null` for `@bug and @another_` and `@bug_` for `@another and @bug_`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're really just looking for words at the end of the input:

```
/@\w+$/
```

Tests:

```
var re = /@\w+$/,
    cases = ['@bug',
             '@bug and me',
             '@bug and @another',
             '@bug and @another and something'];

for (var i=0; i<cases.length; i++)
{
    console.log(cases[i], ':', re.test(cases[i]), re.exec(cases[i]));
}

// prints
@bug : true ["@bug"]
@bug and me : false null
@bug and @another : true ["@another"]
@bug and @another and something : false null
```

Comment: The problem is that this string is from <div contenteeditable="true"> and for some reason, FF always adds some tag like: <br _moz_dirty=""> In that case, regex doesn't work

Comment: @Zeljko the example input showed nothing like this, and your question mentioned nothing about HTML. Want a better answer? Ask a better question.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that additional tag before. Any hint on this? I tried negative lookahead and who-knows-what, but it keeps failing.

Comment: @Zeljko like I said, I really have no idea what the input actually looks like, so I can't really be of much help without seeing the real input you're working with. Why not just strip `<br _moz_dirty="">` before passing to the regex? Anyway - it's sleep time for me, I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: Imagine input like:** #bug and #another<br_moz_dirty="">** I can't just strip that tag because other browsers might put something else on their own.

Comment: @Zeljko one last suggestion for the night: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div