# Replaceing dots between characters

Tags: python, regex

So I want to substitude dots in string when there is no space after of before the dots. I have thought this could be easily done with a regular expression but I haven't been able to do it.

I have patterns and I want them to be:

- `h.e.ll.o w.o.r.l.d`: `hello world`
- `h.e.ll.o w.o.r.l.d`: `hello world`
- `hello. world`: `hello. world`

I have tried the following patterns:

```
\w+(\.)+\w+
\w+(\.+\w+)
\w+\.+\w+
```

I always get something like: `he.ll.o wo.rl.d`

I am using python's `re` module to match and replace with the following code:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\w+\.+\w+', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('.', ''), 'h.e.ll.o w.o.r.l.d')
'he.llo wo.rl.d'
```

Comment: similar search in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584981/javascript-regex-find-a-word-not-followed-by-space-character

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In all your patterns you consume a char after the dot, so there is no chance to match it in the next iteration with the first `\w+` (as it must consume at least 1 word char).

**To fix your approach**, you may match 1+ word chars followed with 1+ repetitions of `.` followed with 1+ word chars:

```
re.sub(r'\w+(?:\.+\w+)*', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('.', ''), s)
```

Here is the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Nr4hAd).

Another **approach to remove `.` between word chars** is

```
re.sub(r'\b\.\b', '', s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OHdqNU/1). Here, `.` is only matched in case it is within word chars.

Alternatively, you may use this approach **to match any `.` not enclosed with whitespace**:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\s)\.(?!\s)', '', 'h.e.ll.o w.o.r.l.d')
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/UQGIO33160) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yUsY0/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\s)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!\s)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: This regex fails for `'. h.e.ll.o. w.o.r.l.d'`

Comment: I works, thank you. I was thinking the other way a round, this made the trick

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach.

`re.sub(r'\.(?=\w)', '', 'h.e.ll.o. w.o.r.l.d')`

- `\.` a dot
- `(?=\w)` Look ahead: Checks if there is \w after the dot.