# How to parse editable DIV's text with browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I make div as editable. while i tried to parse div's text, i was needed to do the below regular expression.

```
innerDOM = "<div style="cursor: text;">I had downloaded all the material from the Intern,<br>You will find</div><div style="cursor: text;">&nbsp;</div><div style="cursor: text;">dfvdfvdvdfvdfvdvdvdf</div><div style="cursor: text;">&nbsp;</div><div style="cursor: text;">dfvdfvdvdfvdfvdfvdfvd</div>"

innerDOM.replace(/<div style="cursor: text">/g, "<br>").replace(/<\/div>/g, "");
```

Above regular expression works good in firefox and chrome. But not in IE. What changes should i do?

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/BmTNP/4/) for better understanding...

Comment: Do *not* use a RegExp, especially not *that* RegExp to parse HTML. You already experienced that it's not reliable. Can you show the code which generates the value of `innerDOM`?

Comment: And where did you get THAT string? I hope that you didn't literally copy-paste HTML strings in JavaScript code? (especially since the quotes in the string are not escaped...)

Comment: actually, i make DIV as editable. while i hit enter and type in IE, each line it construct DOM with divs instead of <br>. But working good in IE and Chrome. I get that string using $("#div-edit").html().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//FINAL ANSWER
var domString = "", temp = "";

$("#div-editable div").each(function()
            {
                temp = $(this).html();
                domString += "<br>" + ((temp == "<br>") ? "" : temp);
            });

alert(domString);
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/BmTNP/5/) for answer.

Comment: Thanks to @Laoujin and @ Rob W for their valuable input.

Comment: Very nice. This seems to work in Firefox (Mac) on iOS (Safari), Safari (Mac) and Chrome (Mac). There is one thing I'd change though, instead of using '<br>', I'd use "\n", because I want to write to a file afterwards. Any opinions about this?

Comment: The above solution breaks in windows chrome.

Answer (score 4):

DOM manipulation is one of the things [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) was made for. Investing in learning jQuery will take you a long way towards writing DOM traversal and modification.

```
$("div[style='cursor: text']").unwrap().prepend("<br>");
```

[`unwrap`](http://www.jquery.com/unwrap/) deletes the element but keeps the children intact. The jQuery [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) is used to select all `divs` with the cursor style attribute. You can run it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FMmt2/).

You could make this more robust as currently you would not select a div with more or less whitespace or with other trivial differences. For example: `<div style="cursor:text;">` is not matched by the above selector. You can work around this shortcoming by introducing a CSS class that sets the cursor. In this case `<div style="cursor: text">` becomes `<div class='textCursor'>` and you can use the class selector: `$("div.textCursor")`

Comment: @RobW "How do I do this? This is what I have using regular expressions." "Don't use regular expressions, use jQuery instead, like this". The fact that the "like this" part was incomplete doesn't mean that the advise to use jQuery was wrong. The question doesn't say that the answer must continue to use regular expressions for some reason.

Comment: @Laou I'm not suggesting a RegExp, but DOM manipulation from [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/). Your updated answer is still not an improvement, because it didn't address points 1 and 2 from my previous comment. EDIT: From a comment in the OP you can derive that the OP is using jQuery. Feel free to post a jQuery answer, but don't forget to address the other points.

Comment: @RobW I am using jquery as well in my app. So if solution contains jquery work, no problem in my side.

Comment: @Laoujin unwrap will remove the DIV. but i need to replace it with <br>

Comment: Deleted my own answer, because the OPs question is covered well in your answer. For the ones who are interested, the pure JS solution is available at http://jsfiddle.net/wqsSf/1/ (works even in IE6).

Comment: @Laoujin Future readers do not know the previous context of the conversation, and it doesn't serve any purpose any more, so I've deleted some irrelevant comments. If you've read this comment, I'll delete this one as well.

Comment: @Laoujin your solution is not working. see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/BmTNP/4/)

Comment: @user10> The code does work, the wrong output is because you didn't integrate it completely correctly. But since you already found a solution yourself there is little use in updating my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

i found this solution in this site:

```
$editables = $('[contenteditable=true'];

$editables.filter("p,span").on('keypress',function(e){
 if(e.keyCode==13){ //enter && shift

  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
  if (window.getSelection) {
      var selection = window.getSelection(),
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
          br = document.createElement("br"),
          textNode = document.createTextNode($("<div>&nbsp;</div>").text()); //Passing " " directly will not end up being shown correctly
      range.deleteContents();//required or not?
      range.insertNode(br);
      range.collapse(false);
      range.insertNode(textNode);
      range.selectNodeContents(textNode);

      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      return false;
  }

   }
});
```