# Get contenteditable element value

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

How do I get the value of a `contenteditable` element?

Right now I just use `innerHTML` to get the content of the element, which would result carriage returns as `<br>` tags, so I need to convert `<br>` tags to `\n` right now.

Is there another more proper way to get the value from a `contenteditable` element that I just don't know about?

**Update:**

In a `textarea` element when you get the value e.g. `textarea.value` the content is intact, like the carriage returns. Is there a similar way to get value from a `contenteditable` element or I am forced to replace values?

```
content.innerHTML.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n")
```

`element.textContent` only gets the text, carriage returns not included. So this does not solve my problem.

Comment: You might need to check **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the text content from a contenteditable div through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593626/get-the-text-content-from-a-contenteditable-div-through-javascript)

Comment: @JohnIdol I already saw that question and the answers do not answer this question. But it did answer my other question.

Comment: You need to consider line breaks implied by block elements as well. For example, your contenditable element's `innerHTML` could be `<p>First paragraph</p><p>Second paragraph</p>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to let users edit text the only clean solution is to go with a text area as you figured out yourself.

If for some reason you can't or you don't wanna use a textarea you have write your own bit of code that will convert those `<br>` into carriage returns. There is no automatic way of doing this because there could be all sorts of markup in there.

Comment: I just thought there might be an automatic way that I did not know about. thanks!