# format tag system while typing contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a tagging system, such as the one twitter and facebook uses where you can just type @ and automatically it will popup the people you are able to tag in your post (such as a common socialnetwork thing) I've spent a few days trying to come up with a solution because all the answers that i've searched and tried just doesn't make it up for me, it doesn't work as neat as I need it to be.

Example (I can type in my post body):

Hello **@andy22** how have you been?

and as you type, I need to format the text part **@andy22** to another font color.

This is the solution I came up with, it almost works perfect since it also works when you paste a text. But the real issue is when you put the caret or the cursor somewhere else in that text and you start typing right there, it just always goes back to the end of the text. And I figured that if I want to change that, I would actually need to change the whole code, so what can I do?

HTML

```
<div class="editable" id="ee1" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

JS / JQuery

on type event for the div.

```
function tagType() {
var typing;
var format;
$('.editable').on('input', function(e) {
    typing = $(this);
    format = checkFormat(typing.getPreText());
    addFormat(format);
});
}
```

get the text with the html function

```
$.fn.getPreText = function () {
    var ce = $("<pre />").html(this.html());
    if ($.browser.webkit)
      ce.find("div").replaceWith(function() { return "\n" + this.innerHTML; });
    if ($.browser.msie)
      ce.find("p").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML + "<br>"; });
    if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie)
      ce.find("br").replaceWith("\n");

    return ce.text();
};
```

change format of the text as you type functions

```
function checkFormat(postbody) {
var body = postbody;
var format = '';
var flag_tagformat = 0;
var start_tagformat = '<span style="color:#0284fe">';
var end_tagformat = '</span>';

for(var i = 0; i < htmlCount(postbody); i++) {
    if(postbody[i] == ' ') {
        flag_tagformat = 0;
    }
    if(postbody[i] == '@' || flag_tagformat == 1) {
        format = format + start_tagformat + postbody[i] + end_tagformat;
        flag_tagformat = 1;
    } else {
        format = format + postbody[i];
    }
}

return format;
}

function htmlCount(thehtml) {
    thehtml = thehtml+'';
    return thehtml.length;
}

function addFormat(format) {
    $('.editable').empty();
    pasteHtmlAtCaret(format);
}
```

and the last one, is the function that pastes the html into the div, but this also sets the caret/cursor to the last character and since it pastes the whole thing, it will always set it to the last character, even if you move the caret/cursor to elsewhere in the text it will type the first character and then if you keep typing it's going to remain typing but in the last character of the div itself.

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
var sel, range;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
        // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);

        // Preserve the selection
        if (lastNode) {
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    // IE < 9
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
}
}
```

If I need to provide more info, let me know, also if there is another better approach on how to do it, i'd like to know.

I did do some of these codes, but I also took 2 codes from here of which I'm going to give credit.

Tim Down answer: [Insert html at caret in a contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div/6691294#6691294)

Nick Craver answer: [Extracting text from a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div)

Thank you.